# Choosing sponsor for f1 visa

Tags: usa, f1-visas, us-visa, english-language, visa-sponsors

I'd like to go to US for 2/3 months to study an English intensive course, the college that I'm planning to enroll asks for 9k USD funds. I have 2 available sponsors which I'm confuse which one to choose: my far relative who is a resident in US and a close friend of the family in my home country. Which one would you recommend me to choose? Are my chances high of rejection because they're not my immediate relatives?
As background I'm in my early 20's and I'll start college (in my country) next semester, that's why I can only go for couple of months.
Any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: Why are these people willing to sponsor you?

Answer (score 2):

When assessing sponsors, immigration are interested in two things.

1. Are they able to afford to sponsor you?
2. Is the reason for them sponsoring you plausible?

Since you haven't indicated a reason why either would sponsor you, we cannot say which would be best. Neither seems like a good bet based on what you have said.

Being resident in the US does not help.

Comment: Whoever the sponsor I am planning to say the truth as 'plausible reason' for
them agreeing to sponsor me is that I know them since ever and 
moreover I will be in the US for only a month so my sponsor will not have to bear a lot of expenses. Based on the above information, can we say that visa rejection chance is high enough to better not risk spending $500 dollars 
in application process?  Is the reason plausible enough to 
ensure a good chance? Also, if I get rejected, Does this current rejection affect chances of getting visa next year with a different sponsor?
I appreciate your help!

Comment: Your chances of rejection depend on a huge number of things that you haven't told us and I don't want to speculate about your chances.